# Calculating LOOCV with adjusted R-square scoring parameter

Tags: linear-regression, cross-validation, scoring, leave-one-out, loocv

I have dataset where I transformed categorical dataset into numerical by dummies and I ran simple linear regression model to predict dependent variable. I got adjusted R-square as `0.66`.
Now I want to cross validate my model with leave one out method and want to see the `LOOCV` adjusted r-square, whether it is similar to my pre cross validation model.

```py
cv = LeaveOneOut()
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/LENOVO/Documents/Diwali_Impact_coding/Modelling/Model_Data.xlsx', usecols=['PMlog', 'Temp', 'RH', 'WSlog', 'Type', 'Popu', 'FRPlog', 'Region'], sheet_name='City_cook2')
data.dropna(subset=['PMlog', 'Temp', 'RH', 'WSlog'], inplace=True)

data_log1 = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['Type', 'Region', 'Popu'])  # all NUMERICAL FEATURES
X = data_log1.loc[:, data_log1.columns != 'PMlog']  # Indepenedent/Predictor Variables
y = data_log1.loc[:, 'PMlog']  # Dependent Variable
    
model_LR = LinearRegression()
    
model_LR.fit(X,y)

def adj_Rsqr(model_LR, X, y):
   xx = 1 - (1 - model_LR.score(X, y)) * (len(y) - 1) / (len(y) - X.shape[1] - 1)
   return xx

adj_Rsqr(model_LR,X,y)  # 0.66
scores = cross_val_score(model_LR, X, y, scoring=adj_Rsqr, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
mean(scores)
```

My scores values are coming `nan`
Can anybody help me why its is coming as nan. Also, if I uses scoring as `R2` then also it is coming as nan but with not other scoring such as absolute error etc.

Thank you for every help.

Comment: Did you have the time to have a look at my answer? Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Cross validation is the process of splitting your data into a training and a test split for the purpose of model validation on *kind of* different data sets. When you apply `LeaveOneOut` cross validation, the test split is just one sample and the train split is all the other samples. An r-squared does not make a lot of sense just for a single sample in the test split.

When I coded LOOCV for `sklearn`'s diabetes dataset to reproduce the behavior you got, I got the following warning:

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples.
  warnings.warn(msg, UndefinedMetricWarning)
```

Consequently, a possible solution could be using `KFold` cross validation and choosing a high `k`, where `k < n/2`, so that you have at least two samples in each test split.

Your scoring function can be improved: You could use a `sklearn.metrics.make_scorer`. `make_scorer` accepts a scoring function. According to the documentation, the scoring function must have the signature `score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs)`.

So, a scoring function and a scorer could look like this in your case:

```
def adjusted_r2_score(y_true, y_pred, n_features): # It takes the actual and predicted values instead of the estimator
    r2 = r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
    n_samples = len(y_true)
    adj_r2 = 1 - (1 - r2) * (n_samples - 1) / (n_samples - n_features - 1)
    return adj_r2

adj_r2_scorer = make_scorer(adjusted_r2_score, greater_is_better=True, n_features=X.shape[1])
```

But then, your code has to change a little bit:

```
model_LR = LinearRegression()
model_LR.fit(X, y)

y_pred = model_LR.predict(X) # This step is new
score_no_cv = adjusted_r2_score(y, y_pred, X.shape[1])
print(f"Adjusted R-squared without CV: {score_no_cv:.4f}")

# Create a KFold cross-validation object with k as half of the number of samples
n_samples = len(y)
k = n_samples // 2
kf = KFold(n_splits=k)

# Calculate the Adjusted R-squared score with KFold cross-validation
scores_kf = cross_val_score(model_LR, X, y, cv=kf, scoring=adj_r2_scorer)
avg_score_kf = np.mean(scores_kf)
print(f"Average Adjusted R-squared with {k}-fold CV: {avg_score_kf:.4f}")
```

I liked the question, I had fun thinking about it.